# How to calculate new values from numbers with relations in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, math

I have the following data:

```
[
    { "names" : [ "a3","printed","black" ], "value" : 15 },
    { "names" : [ "a3","copied","black" ], "value" : 87 },
    { "names" : [ "a3","printed","color" ], "value" : 37 },
    { "names" : [ "a3","printed","color","full" ], "value" : 37 },
    { "names" : [ "a3","copied","color","single" ], "value" : 0 },
    { "names" : [ "a3","copied","color","full" ], "value" : 44 },
    { "names" : [ "a3","scanned" ], "value" : 288 },
    { "names" : [ "total" ], "value" : 242142 },
    { "names" : [ "scanned" ], "value" : 67411 },
    { "names" : [ "copied","black" ], "value" : 79997 },
    { "names" : [ "copied","full","color" ], "value" : 809 },
    { "names" : [ "copied","single","color" ], "value" : 0 },
    { "names" : [ "printed","two","color" ], "value" : 0 },
    { "names" : [ "printed","black" ], "value" : 120665 },
    { "names" : [ "printed","full","color" ], "value" : 40657 }
]
```

I organized the relationships between those values in the following way:

```
{    
    "colors" : { "black" : "", "color" : [ "full", "two", "single" ] },
    "functions" : { "scanned" : "", "total" : [ "printed", "copied", "faxed" ] },
    "papers" : { "a3" : "" }
}
```

using this script I was managed to get almost all the values I was looking for:

```js
function calculateValues(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).reduce(function (r, k) {
        var v;
        if (k === 'value') {
            return r;
        }
        v = calculateValues(o[k]);
        if (o[k].value === null) {
            o[k].value = v;
        }
        values[k] = (values[k] || 0) + o[k].value;
        return r + o[k].value;
    }, 0);
}

var data = [{ names: ["a3", "printed", "black"], value: 15 }, { names: ["a3", "copied", "black"], value: 87 }, { names: ["a3", "printed", "color"], value: 37 }, { names: ["a3", "printed", "color", "full"], value: 37 }, { names: ["a3", "copied", "color", "single"], value: 0 }, { names: ["a3", "copied", "color", "full"], value: 44 }, { names: ["a3", "scanned"], value: 288 }, { names: ["total"], value: 242142 }, { names: ["scanned"], value: 67411 }, { names: ["copied", "black"], value: 79997 }, { names: ["copied", "full", "color"], value: 809 }, { names: ["copied", "single", "color"], value: 0 }, { names: ["printed", "two", "color"], value: 0 }, { names: ["printed", "black"], value: 120665 }, { names: ["printed", "full", "color"], value: 40657 }],
    relations = { colors: { "black": "", color: ["full", "two", "single"] }, functions: { scanned: "", total: ["printed", "copied", "faxed"] }, papers: { "a3": "" } },
    priorities = ['functions', 'colors', 'papers'], // as long as keys of objects are not ordered
    order = {},
    result = {},
    values = {},
    i = 0;

priorities.forEach(function (p) {
    Object.keys(relations[p]).forEach(function (k) {
        order[k] = ++i;
        Array.isArray(relations[p][k]) && relations[p][k].forEach(function (a) {
            order[a] = ++i;
        });
    });
});

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var names = a.names.slice();
    names.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (order[a] || 0) - (order[b] || 0);
    });
    if (relations.functions.total.indexOf(names[0]) !== -1) {
        names.unshift('total');
    }
    names.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || { value: null };
    }, result).value = a.value;
});

calculateValues(result.total);
// calculateCount(result.scanned); 

console.log(values);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

But I'm missing a few things. for example:

> **a3 printed black** is 15
>
> **a3 printed color** is 37
>
> what is **a3 printed**? (52)

and another one is:

> a3 copied color full is: 44
>
> a3 copied color single is: 0
>
> what is **a3 copied color**? (44)

and another one is:

> a3 printed color is: 37
>
> a3 copied color is: 44 (based on the value we found in the above
>   example)
>
> what is **a3 color**? 81

You should probably get the idea of what I've meant is missing here.

Comment: Thanks for @NinaScholz for the script here.

Answer (score 1):

You could search the `result` object for the given indicators and iterate all properties. Then count only values that match.

```js
function getValue(names) {

    function iter(o, p) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            var q = p.slice();
            k === q[0] && q.shift();
            if (q.length) {
                o[k] !== null && typeof o[k] === 'object' && iter(o[k], q);
                return;
            }
            v += o[k].value || 0;
        });
    }

    var v = 0;
    names.sort(sortByOrder);
    iter(result, names);
    return v;
}

function calculateValues(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).reduce(function (r, k) {
        var v;
        if (k === 'value') {
            return r;
        }
        v = calculateValues(o[k]);
        if (o[k].value === null) {
            o[k].value = v;
        }
        values[k] = (values[k] || 0) + o[k].value;
        return r + o[k].value;
    }, 0);
}

function sortByOrder(a, b) {
    return (order[a] || 0) - (order[b] || 0);
}

function getSums(a) {
    console.log(a.join(' '), getValue(a));
}

var data = [{ names: ["a3", "printed", "black"], value: 15 }, { names: ["a3", "copied", "black"], value: 87 }, { names: ["a3", "printed", "color", "full"], value: 37 }, { names: ["a3", "copied", "color", "single"], value: 0 }, { names: ["a3", "copied", "color", "full"], value: 44 }, { names: ["a3", "scanned"], value: 288 }, { names: ["total"], value: 242142 }, { names: ["scanned"], value: 67411 }, { names: ["copied", "black"], value: 79997 }, { names: ["copied", "full", "color"], value: 809 }, { names: ["copied", "single", "color"], value: 0 }, { names: ["printed", "two", "color"], value: 0 }, { names: ["printed", "black"], value: 120665 }, { names: ["printed", "full", "color"], value: 40657 }],
    relations = { colors: { "black": "", color: ["full", "two", "single"] }, functions: { scanned: "", total: ["printed", "copied", "faxed"] }, papers: { "a3": "" } },
    priorities = ['functions', 'colors', 'papers'], // as long as keys of objects are not ordered
    order = {},
    result = {},
    values = {},
    i = 0;

priorities.forEach(function (p) {
    Object.keys(relations[p]).forEach(function (k) {
        order[k] = ++i;
        Array.isArray(relations[p][k]) && relations[p][k].forEach(function (a) {
            order[a] = ++i;
        });
    });
});

data.forEach(function (a) {
    var names = a.names.slice();
    names.sort(sortByOrder);
    if (relations.functions.total.indexOf(names[0]) !== -1) {
        names.unshift('total');
    }
    names.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || { value: null };
    }, result).value = a.value;
});

calculateValues(result.total);
// calculateCount(result.scanned);

getSums(['a3', 'color']);
getSums(['a3', 'black']);
getSums(['a3', 'printed', 'two', 'color']);
getSums(['a3', 'printed', 'full', 'color']);

// the wanted use cases

getSums(['a3', 'printed', 'black']);          // 15
getSums(['a3', 'printed', 'color']);          // 37
getSums(['a3', 'printed']);                   // 52


getSums(['a3', 'copied', 'color', 'full']);   // 44
getSums(['a3', 'copied', 'color', 'single']); //  0
getSums(['a3', 'copied', 'color']);           // 44

getSums(['a3', 'printed', 'color']);          // 37
getSums(['a3', 'copied', 'color']);           // 44
getSums(['a3', 'color']);                     // 81


console.log(values);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It seems that this approach is going to create some problems because for example if I have a3 printed two color and a3 printed full color and a3 printed color then a3 printed color contains the sum of a3 printed two color and a3 printed full color so to sum up all of these would be wrong because a3 color needs to only include in this case a3 printed color which is already the sum of 2 other values

Comment: Can we make it that every function and every paper will give the sum of colors? which total, black, color. so for example I will get printed color, printed black, a3 color, a3 black etc... although for this example I already know printed color and printed black for other cases it should help

Comment: Pleas help me with my last comment. It seems so complicated to get around this.

Comment: i really do not understand the problem. please add the use cases to your question, with the expected results.

Comment: I just did it. please take a look and see if the idea is more easy to understand now.

Comment: please see edit, you get all values from your use cases.

Comment: You didn't notice I changed a little bit the data variable in the snippet.

Comment: I added this: { names: ["a3", "printed", "color"], value: 37 }

Comment: it does not work if you insert a random value somwhere, because the path to `'a3'` is disconnected. the keyword color need to be followed by either `'two'` or `'full'`. the whole path would be `['total', 'printed', 'color', 'full', 'a3']` or `['total', 'printed', 'color', 'two', 'a3']`.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked at your other question, but to me it seems that for just getting the sum, you can do with a much simpler function.

- Select entries that have all desired values in their `names` array using `filter`
- Add their `value` properties using `reduce`

```js
function getEntriesWithValues(entries, values) {
  return entries
    .filter(e => values.every(v => e.names.includes(v)));
};
  
function sumValue(v1, v2) { return v1 + v2.value; }

var data = [
    { "names" : [ "a3","printed","black" ], "value" : 15 },
    { "names" : [ "a3","copied","black" ], "value" : 87 },
    { "names" : [ "a3","printed","color","full" ], "value" : 37 },
    { "names" : [ "a3","copied","color","single" ], "value" : 0 },
    { "names" : [ "a3","copied","color","full" ], "value" : 44 },
    { "names" : [ "a3","scanned" ], "value" : 288 },
    { "names" : [ "total" ], "value" : 242142 },
    { "names" : [ "scanned" ], "value" : 67411 },
    { "names" : [ "copied","black" ], "value" : 79997 },
    { "names" : [ "copied","full","color" ], "value" : 809 },
    { "names" : [ "copied","single","color" ], "value" : 0 },
    { "names" : [ "printed","two","color" ], "value" : 0 },
    { "names" : [ "printed","black" ], "value" : 120665 },
    { "names" : [ "printed","full","color" ], "value" : 40657 }
];

function getSumFromData(values) {
  return getEntriesWithValues(data, values).reduce(sumValue, 0);
};

var entriesWithA3Black = getEntriesWithValues(data, ["a3", "black"]);
var sumForA3Black = entriesWithA3Black.reduce(sumValue, 0);

console.log("Sum for A3 + black: " + sumForA3Black);
console.log("Sum for A3 + color: " + getSumFromData(["a3", "color"]));
```